# How to run Webkit nightly builds on Windows without Safari?

Tags: webkit

I've downloaded latest nightly builds from official Webkit site. It contains some exes, dlls, and resources. However, none of exes can be performed.

I also tried to google some answers, they all mentioned one run-safari script or run-nightly-webkit.cmd, but both of them didn't get shipped with nightly build. So, how to run this nightly builds?

Thanks.

Comment: Yet another example of incompetent mods closing legitimate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not run them directly outside the building environment, because there are some environment variable should be specified.

The easy way is to run it in the building environment, you could choose MiniBrowser as starting point.

Another way, you many mention each message while you run it outside which may remind you to setup something or missed something, then Google it.

Finally, you also could study run-safari script in detail.

Here is a reference for you to check the building steps:
  http://blog.ashodnakashian.com/2012/01/building-webkit-on-windows-7-with-vs2010/

Good Luck!